# Not showing terminal in FAILSAFE mode

Tags: dual-boot, graphics

Pressing ALT CTRL F1 doesn't open the terminal when I'm trying to boot from my hard drive. There's just this black screen. When I do it from a LIVEUSB the terminal opens but executing the commands show am error of can't locate package. Please help.

Comment: Reboot your system in normal mode and then press CTRL+ALT+F1 you will see the login terminal.

Comment: Actually I was tackling the problem of Ubuntu running in Low Graphics mode. As per the answer given:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error... It is necessary to boot in FAILSAFE mode.

Comment: If low graphics mode is due to install of graphic drivers then go to recovery mode and select root then uninstall the drivers you can  see your ubuntu gui again

Answer (score 0):

If your Ubuntu is running in low graphics. try thi 
Run Ubuntu in normal mode. when it shows low graphic error, use CTRL+ALT+F1 to enter into login terminal. Use your credentials to login. then run these commands.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

Comment: It says 'It cannot be downloaded'. I have a Wifi connection. How do I connect to download the package when I'm shut out of Ubuntu?

Comment: I tried re installing Ubuntu desktop using a boot repair live cd. It ran without any errors but the low graphics error still persists...